# Angular js Replace html string with Tokens

Tags: c#, angularjs, sitecore

I have a Value coming from model that is relatively a huge html String. It also has a token that needs to be replaced with a value from Angular. I am trying to see how to get both of ends meet.

my Html

```
<h2 class="sub-title"> @Model.WelcomeText </h2>
```

Now this Welcome text is a relatively a html string that has a token. Something like this

```
 "Hi @@Name , Welcome to our Website. Click <a href='#'> here </a>
 for more details. <small> For more details please visit blah blah
 </small>
```

Now i need to replace @@Name with a model value in my controller- $scope.Name

I tried

```
<h2 class="sub-title" ng-init= $scope.welcomeText('@Model.WelcomeText') </h2>
```

and then in my controller

```
function welcomeText(str)
{
  return str.replace('@@Name',$scope.Name);
}
```

But it breaks in the html itself because of $scope.welcomeText has invalid values inside ng-init

Any pointers on how to achieve this?  The Model.Title is from a Sitecore CMS. I dont have that value in JS

Comment: Why don't you create one variable in $scope as `welcomeText` and getter should have the logic or replacing @@Name with $scope.Name and then use it in angular way rather than `@Model.WelcomeText` use `ng-model=$scope.welcomText` .

Comment: @PM. Icannot. I dont have the value with me in Js. I Actual, the value Model.Title is coming from a CMS system.

Comment: Have you considered exposing a RESTful service from Sitecore that you could call with AJAX within Angular?  This would replace your Razor code, @Model.WelcomeText.

Comment: @DougCouto - I considered that, but that was too costly for a simple header text. I did something else and that worked. I have put that in answer. Not the best of solution but works..

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this.  Not sure if this is the ideal solution but atleast it works.

```
    //Added a div with hidden class to get the value.      
    <div class="hidden" id="inp-title-server" /> @Model.Title  </div>
    <h2 class="sub-title" data-ng-bind-html="$scope.header"></h2>
```

Then in my controller,

```
var title = $("#inp-title-server").text();
$scope.header = title.replace('@@Name', $scope.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use replace function of string.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("ctrl",['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.WelcomeText = "Hi @@Name , Welcome to our Website. Click <a href='#'> here </a> for more details. <small> For more details please visit blah blah </small>";
 $scope.UserName = "ABC";
 $scope.WelcomeText = $scope.WelcomeText.replace("@@Name",$scope.UserName);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>   
<html>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h4 class="sub-title" ng-bind="WelcomeText"> </h4>    
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I cannot because i get the value from Server. dont have that value in Javascript.